# IBM Watson Discovery - How to list uploaded documents?

Tags: rest, curl, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to get the ID-s of all documents uploaded to [IBM Watson Discovery API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery/discovery)

It's not obvious from the documentation, but I guess it must be possible?

The structure is:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Environment                                      |
|                                                  |
|              +--------------------------------+  |
|              | Collection                     |  |
|              |                                |  |
|              |              +--------------+  |  |
|              |              | Document     |  |  |
|              |              |              |  |  |
|              |              +--------------+  |  |
|              |                                |  |
|              +--------------------------------+  |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

**How can I get a list of all documents in a collection?**

.

I have tried:

**[Collections -> List collection fields](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery/discovery#list-collection-fields)**

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "{url}/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/fields?version=2019-04-30"`

**[Queries -> Query a collection (GET)](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery/discovery#query-a-collection-get)**

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "{url}/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/query?version=2019-04-30"`

**[Environments -> Get environment info](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery/discovery#get-environment-info)**

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "{url}/v1/environments/{environment_id}?version=2019-04-30"`

**[Training data -> List training data](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery/discovery#list-training-data)**

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "{url}/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/training_data?version=2019-04-30"`

None of these give the list of documents.

.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@Catbelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825654/812973), the correct way to get a list of documents is:

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "{url}/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/query?version=2019-04-30&return=id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query endpoint is the only way to do this - if you set the `return` value equal to `id` you will only get ids back.  (I am a IBM Watson employee)

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution.

Comment: @catbelly how does that work on Watson Discovery v2?